# Changing name of ViewController causes app to crash?

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch, ios4, uiviewcontroller

I created a new View-based iPhone app in XCode (4.0) using iOS SDK 4.3. I then changed the name of the ViewController from `MyProjectNameViewController` to `LoginViewController`. I also replaced every single instance I could find of `MyProjectNameViewController` with `LoginViewController`, and I have double checked all of the links in interface builder.

Yet, when I try to run the app, It crashes:

```
2011-06-29 10:21:36.927 Monitoring[12580:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<LoginViewController 0x4b26bf0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key password.'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00dc05a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00f14313 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00dc04e1 -[NSException raise] + 17
    3   Foundation                          0x00792677 _NSSetUsingKeyValueSetter + 135
    4   Foundation                          0x007925e5 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 285
    5   UIKit                               0x0020e30c -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 112
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x00d368cf -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 239
    7   UIKit                               0x0020cd23 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1041
    8   UIKit                               0x0020eab7 -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:] + 168
    9   UIKit                               0x000c4628 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 70
    10  UIKit                               0x000c2134 -[UIViewController loadView] + 120
    11  UIKit                               0x000c200e -[UIViewController view] + 56
    12  UIKit                               0x00035d42 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 51
    13  MyProjectName                       0x000022c7 -[MyProjectNameAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 135
    14  UIKit                               0x00012c89 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1163
    15  UIKit                               0x00014d88 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 439
    16  UIKit                               0x0001f617 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1533
    17  UIKit                               0x00017abf -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 71
    18  UIKit                               0x0001cf2e _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576
    19  GraphicsServices                    0x00ff9992 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x00da1944 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x00d01cf7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x00cfef83 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x00cfe840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x00cfe761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    25  UIKit                               0x000147d2 -[UIApplication _run] + 623
    26  UIKit                               0x00020c93 UIApplicationMain + 1160
    27  MyProjectName                       0x00002209 main + 121
    28  MyProjectName                       0x00002185 start + 53
```

What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: _I also replaced every single instance I could find_... I think you missed one.

Comment: Seriously, I have checked every single class over and over again, and looked at the source code for the xibs and there isn't a single instance of the old controller name.

Comment: Did you do this by hand or with the Refactor tool?

Comment: I'm guessing that knowing the Refactor tool existed would have saved me a lot of time. But no, I did it by hand.

Comment: Can you undo the rename and *then* use the refactor tool?

Comment: I take it you don't use version control? You could have rolled back and done it that way.

Comment: Yes, I could have done that actually. But it turns out that in the end my code was fine :) The iPhone simulator just didn't update the executable.

Comment: Clean all Targets is your friend when things like this happen, if it doesn't make sense Clean all Targets, Build and Run, then beat head against wall if needed.

Comment: XCode 4.0 only has "Clean" as far as I can tell, and i tried that multiple times. And yes, there was some head-wall interaction going on too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I needed to delete the application from the iPhone Simulator and load it again. Shouldn't it do this automatically???

Comment: It should, but it doesn't. You should raise a bug with Apple.

Answer (score 3):

Did you also rename the classes in your nibs/xibs?

The error message tells you that something wants access to a `password` via KVC, and the object it is called on (`LoginViewController`) does not provide KVC-compliant access to `password`. Did you fiddle with the `password` getters/setters?

Comment: Yea I did rename the classes in the xibs, and I've looked at the source code in the xibs and everything is as it should be. I don't actually have anything called `password` and it is not referenced in any of my code.

Comment: Something is looking for the password... maybe bound in the nib?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you do Build/Clean All Targets, delete the /Build/ directory in your project and then re-run the project. If it still crashes, then you must have missed something.

Comment: Ok, this is bizzare, but I cannot for the life of me find the /Build/ directory. It's usually in the same directory as the project right?

Comment: Found it. Is it normal for it to be in Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProjectName-bkzvxpbmqezjiuekoyjrwutshmkm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyProjectName.app ?

Comment: Yes - it's normal. And an easier way to find it is to use Xcode's Organiser, which shows you where all your projects derived products are - and you can delete them from there.

Answer (score 0):

You have a malformed outlet. The nib is looking for something to tie "password" to, but there is no corresponding property in your controller.

Comment: I don't have any outlet named `password`, nor is it referenced in my code anywhere.

Answer (score -1):

Just get this by: 
1) Select the name you want to change: **MyProjectNameViewController**
2) Edit -> Refactor, fill in to "**LoginViewController**"
That's it. But pay attention if on storyboardID might to be changed manually if you set it same as view controller before.